# How to report results of RL with high variance?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I run Q-learning and SARSA algortihms on the same problem but the results fluctuate heavily and when I draw them, there is no smooth graph. How should I repost the results? I run algorithms for 500 runs and 40000 episodes; however, it seems that 500 runs are not sufficient, and because of timing, it is difficult to increase the number of runs.

This graph shows `reward_q` which is a vector of 40000 and each element number shows the summation of rewards in each episods for 500 runs, and I draw the graph based on number of episodes vs `reward_q/n_runs`.

**Note:** The title of the x-axis is not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. One way is to calculate a moving average and moving standard deviation.
2. My preferable method is smoothing (like tensorboard's smoothing function). Here is a very nice [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011419/is-it-possible-to-call-tensorboard-smooth-function-manually) in python. Just tune the weight parameter to get the results you want. For example:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome :) If my answer completely answers your question please consider ticking it as such.